# How do I use a generic in an interface other than the one specified in the parent class?

Tags: java

This is a parent class I inherit from it and I want to use another generic in the interface

```
public class BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema<C extends BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema.Config>
        extends AKBARSCard2AccountSchema<C> implements ParameterizedPayment<BaitushumAdapter.Parameters> {

    private BaitushumAdapter.Parameters parameters;

    @Override
    public void setParameters(BaitushumAdapter.Parameters parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
```

This is the inheritor class
[image]

```
public class JskkBaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema extends BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema<JskkBaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema.Config>
        implements ParameterizedPayment<JskkBaitushumAdapter.Parameters> {

    private JskkBaitushumAdapter.Parameters parameters;

    @Override
    public void setParameters(JskkBaitushumAdapter.Parameters parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
```

Parameters are inherited(
They are in the Baitushum class)

```
public static class Parameters extends ParameterizedPayment.Parameters {
```

Parameters are parents

```
public class JskkBaitushumAdapter {

    public static class Parameters extends BaitushumAdapter.Parameters {
```

Comment: FYI it is hard to answer this question when none of the code examples compile. In the future, please try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema` and `JskkBaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema` specify different concrete types for the `ParameterizedPayment` type parameter. To fix this, you'll need to make `BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema` take an additional type parameter:

```
public class BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema<C extends BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema.Config,
        P extends BaitushumAdapter.Parameters>
        extends AKBARSCard2AccountSchema<C> implements ParameterizedPayment<P> {

    private P parameters;

    @Override
    public void setParameters(P parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, the declaration for `JskkBaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema` changes to this:

```
public class JskkBaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema
        extends BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema<JskkBaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema.Config,
        JskkBaitushumAdapter.Parameters> {
```

Note two additional changes:

1. It isn't necessary to specify that `JskkBaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema` implements `ParameterizedPayment` anymore, since this is implied by extending `BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema`
2. The `parameters` field and `setParameters` methods can be inherited from `BaitushumAKBARSCard2AccountSchema` and do not need to be redeclared.